# setting the value of a given cell in a jintArray

Tags: java, arrays, java-native-interface, set, int

I get the arr int[] from the JVM and want to set a value in it at a specified index,
like this:

```
jintArray arr;
jint* ints = _env->GetIntArrayElements(arr, false);
int newvalue = 4;

_env->SetIntArrayRegion(ints, 3, 1, &newvalue); // this works
inst[3] = newvalue; // this failed !!!
```

Can you tell me why the second assignment fails???
It should work and be much faster (no method call).

Thanks,
Luc

Comment: Typo in question or code? The array is named `ints` and not `inst` as is last line, annotated with "this failed"

Answer (score 0):

As Luc mentioned, he is talking about JNI. The general answer is that the JVM's GC may move around the backing store to an array. The type jintArray is just a typedef which really only indicates a handle to an array.

If you are manipulating the array, you must either use `SetIntArrayRegion`, which copies the passed pointer into the backing store,

OR you can use a combination of `GetIntArrayElements`, which will pin *or copy* the array, followed by `ReleaseIntArrayElements`.

Since jintArray is not a proper C array, you cannot use the indexer operator[].

Answer (score -1):

JIntArray is itself not a primitive array, it just contains a primitive array. To set values, you can use the set(int index, int value) method (see [API](http://gwt-openlayers.sourceforge.net/maven-site-latest/apidocs/org/gwtopenmaps/openlayers/client/util/JIntArray.html) for more details), or you can get the array using the JIntArray toArray() method, and use that array instead.

In your context, the first method would look like this:

```
arr.set(3, newvalue);
```

Comment: My question concerned the JNI topic. We're talking about two different software, here. Thanks anyway. :)